# Construction a loss function from equalities and inequalities constraints

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I have to convert this system of equations

$$\begin{cases} f(x_i) = 0 \\ g(x_i) \leq 0 \\ h(x_i) \leq 0 \end{cases}$$

into an optimization problem. In other words I need a function, say $H = H(x_i)$, such that the values of $\{x_i\}$ at its minimum satisfy the system above.

If I had only the first equation of the system I would set $H = (f(x_i))^2$.

Is
$$H = (f(x_i))^2 + \lambda (g(x_i) + h(x_i))$$
(for $\lambda > 0$) a good choice?

I guess there're better alternatives I didn't find them yet.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and consider the problem $$\begin{cases} f(x) = 0 \\ g(x) \leq 0  \end{cases},\tag{1}$$ where $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),\,\ldots,\,f_m(x))$ and $g(x)=(g_1(x),g_2(x),\,\ldots,\,g_n(x))$.

Define the function $$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\|f(x)\|^2$$ and the minimizing problem
$$\begin{cases} \min_x\quad F(x)  \\ s.t\,\,\,\,\,\, \quad g(x) \leq 0  \end{cases} \tag{2}.$$

Then the values of $\{x_i\}$ which satisfy the system $(1)$ satisfy this minimizing problem $(2)$.

The associated [Lagrangian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) is $$L(x,\lambda)=F(x)+\lambda^Tg(x).$$

Please see [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

You can find related results searching for "[\( \min_x  F(x) \) with  \( g(x) \leq 0\)](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28%20%5Cmin_x%20%20F%28x%29%20%5C%29%20with%20%20%5C%28%20g%28x%29%20%5Cleq%200%5C%29%20)" on SearchOnMath.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I basically need to use this loss function into a python code but I don't see how the Lagrangian would be useful. Maybe I should have specified this at the beginning of my question.

In other words I need some function H such that I can feed a function that minimizes it and return to the minimum, that is the solution of my system.

Comment: Have you tested to optimize the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)$ in your code? The KKT conditions will tell you which optimizer of the Lagrangian is a minimum of $F(x)$.